# use flipbook in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, branding

how can I make a flip book in sharepoint 2013 is there any solution to upload in sharepoint  or is there any jquery to use in page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jquery plugin like [Booklet](http://builtbywill.com/booklet/#/) or [turnjs](http://www.turnjs.com/#) .

- You can see a demo for booklet at
  [Booklet for displaying content on the web in a flipbook layout](http://builtbywill.com/booklet/#/)
- To apply it in SharePoint as web part check [Flip book WebPart for SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2010](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Flip-book-WebPart-for-SharePoint-2013-and-SharePoint-2010.aspx)
- For various jquery flipbook styles check [10 Flipping Effect jQuery Plugins](http://dailydesignnotes.com/flipping-effect-jquery-plugins/)
- Also, check [Flip Book For SharePoint in CodePlex](https://fb.codeplex.com/)

Comment: hi I try codeplex solution but it doesnot work https://fb.codeplex.com/ did you examine it

Comment: how can I  use http://dailydesignnotes.com/flipping-effect-jquery-plugins/ codes in shrepoint

Comment: check this http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Flip-book-WebPart-for-SharePoint-2013-and-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Comment: can any body make a .wsp solution  from http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Flip-book-WebPart-for-SharePoint-2013-and-SharePoint-2010.aspx that I can upload in sharepoint because I donot know much programming

Answer (score 0):

All jQuery solutions require you to add the jQuery library **and** do Scripting.

Plus, you need to add scripting to read the Items from a List or a Library.

Instead, you can go for the Flickity library from http://flickity.metafizzy.co/

It is **not** a jQuery plugin, so no need to load jQuery

**and** you can apply the effect **without** JavaScript coding, because it can be configured in HTML data-attributes

```
example:

     <div class="main-carousel" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left", "contain": true }'>
```

You **do** need to load the Flickity .js library (in the MasterPage, as UserCustomAction or JSLink) ofcourse

But after that your HTML skills *could* be **all** you need
(if your flipbook data is static HTML and does not have to be read from a Library)